# iPython, running parallel computations, is stuck with results in a strange state

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython, ipython-parallel

I'm doing some parallel computations, evaluating the goodness of a fit across many regressions. In doing so (running ~60K computations), I've somehow managed to get iPython into a strange state.

Pushing objects out to all of the nodes

```
%%px
model_analytics = ResultsAnalytics(rows,  store['data_model'])
```

And dispatching the work:

```
%%time 
ar = lview.map(lambda x: model_analytics.generate_prediction_heuristic(x), rows.index)
```

Works fine. In fact, most of the work gets completed:

```
%%time 
completed = ar.progress
print completed
print "Remaining {0} min".format((ar.elapsed/completed) * (len(rows) - completed)/60)
```

> 66229
>
> Remaining 0.0205939930854 min
>
> CPU times: user 211 ms, sys: 163 ms, total: 374 ms
>
> Wall time: 364 ms

But there's one job that doesn't complete!

```
for i, status in enumerate(ar.status): 
    if status != 'ok': print i, status
```

> 35230 None

```
msg = ar.msg_ids[35230]
lview.abort(msg)
print lview.get_result(msg)
print lview.wait(jobs=msg, timeout=5)
```

> `<AsyncResult: unknown>`
>
> False

Edit: I was hoping that I'd be able to get all of the results but the defunct one, but no joy.

```
msgs = ar.msg_ids[0:35230]
res1 = [lview.get_result(msg) for msg in msgs]
print res1[0:10]
```

> `[<AsyncResult: unknown>, <AsyncResult: unknown>, <AsyncResult: unknown>, <AsyncResult: unknown>, <AsyncResult: unknown>, <AsyncResult: unknown>, <AsyncResult: unknown>, <AsyncResult: unknown>, <AsyncResult: unknown>, <AsyncResult: unknown>]`

I haven't yet tried to reproduce this. What could cause this error? Did something wrong? Is there a more graceful way of recovering from this going forward?

Versions:

- IPython: 3.2.1
- pyzmq: 14.7.0
- zeromq: dpkg -l | grep libzmq yields:

  > ii  libzmq-dev:amd64                    2.2.0+dfsg-5                        amd64        lightweight messaging kernel (development files)
  >   ii  libzmq1:amd64                       2.2.0+dfsg-5                        amd64        lightweight messaging kernel (shared library)

Comment: what version of IPython, pyzmq, zeromq are you using?

Comment: @minrk Added versions.

Comment: can you install `libzmq3-dev`? and then reinstall pyzmq? libzmq-2 is super old and has lots of bugs. This may not be related, but it's possible.

Comment: Sure I'll give that a shot.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now, after upgrading to libzmq3 and generally updating things across my python stack to their latest versions. Thanks a lot.